# Android Edittext limit digit input using android:digit and maxlength=1. Return does not work

Tags: java, android

Using XML I have set up an EditText with

```
android:digits="35"
android:numeric="integer"
android:maxlength="1"
android:inputType="number"
android:text="3"
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:editable="true"
```

The problem is that the Character Box which has "Done" if all digits are allowed, now has a "Carriage Return" which does not do anything. I want a "Done" so that I can move on to the next field.

Comment: add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in your xml

Comment: add these `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` and `android:singleLine="true"`